# APi Login do Facebook URL Bloqueada

Tags: php, facebook, login, api

estou com um problema talvez comum para alguns, integração com 'Login do Facebook" já vi alguma postagem referente mas ainda não consegui resolver.

https://www.bombaguete.com.br/delivery/entrar/

Já configurei no facebook, informando os domínios necessários, porém ao tentar logar com o mesmo aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Warning
>   URL bloqueada: O redirecionamento falhou porque o URl usado não está na lista de liberação nas configurações de OAuth do cliente do aplicativo. Verifique se o login de OAuth do cliente e da Web está ativado e adicione todos os domínios do seu aplicativo como URls válidos de redirecionamento de OAuth.

Comment: Talvez seja o servidor que não permita realizar usando a API do PHP, porém da para realizar usando a API do javascript

Comment: como seria feito?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart